# ERC721A internal _transfer

Tags: contract-development, nft, erc-721

I am currently developing a contract that includes a function allowing token transfers without the need for explicit approval. However, I have encountered a challenge as the existing functions within the ERC721A standard do not provide a straightforward solution. In this context, there is an internal function called _transfer that exists within the ERC721 standard, which appears to be a potential avenue for achieving the desired functionality:

```
function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) internal virtual {
        address owner = ownerOf(tokenId);
        if (owner != from) {
            revert ERC721IncorrectOwner(from, tokenId, owner);
        }
        if (to == address(0)) {
            revert ERC721InvalidReceiver(address(0));
        }

        _beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId, 1);

        // Check that tokenId was not transferred by `_beforeTokenTransfer` hook
        owner = ownerOf(tokenId);
        if (owner != from) {
            revert ERC721IncorrectOwner(from, tokenId, owner);
        }

        // Clear approvals from the previous owner
        delete _tokenApprovals[tokenId];

        // Decrease balance with checked arithmetic, because an `ownerOf` override may
        // invalidate the assumption that `_balances[from] >= 1`.
        _balances[from] -= 1;

        unchecked {
            // `_balances[to]` could overflow in the conditions described in `_mint`. That would require
            // all 2**256 token ids to be minted, which in practice is impossible.
            _balances[to] += 1;
        }

        _owners[tokenId] = to;

        emit Transfer(from, to, tokenId);

        _afterTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId, 1);
    }
```

But in the ERC721A there is only tranfserFrom:

```
function transferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) public payable virtual override {
        uint256 prevOwnershipPacked = _packedOwnershipOf(tokenId);

        // Mask `from` to the lower 160 bits, in case the upper bits somehow aren't clean.
        from = address(uint160(uint256(uint160(from)) & _BITMASK_ADDRESS));

        if (address(uint160(prevOwnershipPacked)) != from) _revert(TransferFromIncorrectOwner.selector);

        (uint256 approvedAddressSlot, address approvedAddress) = _getApprovedSlotAndAddress(tokenId);

        // The nested ifs save around 20+ gas over a compound boolean condition.
        if (!_isSenderApprovedOrOwner(approvedAddress, from, _msgSenderERC721A()))
            if (!isApprovedForAll(from, _msgSenderERC721A())) _revert(TransferCallerNotOwnerNorApproved.selector);

        _beforeTokenTransfers(from, to, tokenId, 1);

        // Clear approvals from the previous owner.
        assembly {
            if approvedAddress {
                // This is equivalent to `delete _tokenApprovals[tokenId]`.
                sstore(approvedAddressSlot, 0)
            }
        }

        // Underflow of the sender's balance is impossible because we check for
        // ownership above and the recipient's balance can't realistically overflow.
        // Counter overflow is incredibly unrealistic as `tokenId` would have to be 2**256.
        unchecked {
            // We can directly increment and decrement the balances.
            --ERC721AStorage.layout()._packedAddressData[from]; // Updates: `balance -= 1`.
            ++ERC721AStorage.layout()._packedAddressData[to]; // Updates: `balance += 1`.

            // Updates:
            // - `address` to the next owner.
            // - `startTimestamp` to the timestamp of transfering.
            // - `burned` to `false`.
            // - `nextInitialized` to `true`.
            ERC721AStorage.layout()._packedOwnerships[tokenId] = _packOwnershipData(
                to,
                _BITMASK_NEXT_INITIALIZED | _nextExtraData(from, to, prevOwnershipPacked)
            );

            // If the next slot may not have been initialized (i.e. `nextInitialized == false`) .
            if (prevOwnershipPacked & _BITMASK_NEXT_INITIALIZED == 0) {
                uint256 nextTokenId = tokenId + 1;
                // If the next slot's address is zero and not burned (i.e. packed value is zero).
                if (ERC721AStorage.layout()._packedOwnerships[nextTokenId] == 0) {
                    // If the next slot is within bounds.
                    if (nextTokenId != ERC721AStorage.layout()._currentIndex) {
                        // Initialize the next slot to maintain correctness for `ownerOf(tokenId + 1)`.
                        ERC721AStorage.layout()._packedOwnerships[nextTokenId] = prevOwnershipPacked;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Mask `to` to the lower 160 bits, in case the upper bits somehow aren't clean.
        uint256 toMasked = uint256(uint160(to)) & _BITMASK_ADDRESS;
        assembly {
            // Emit the `Transfer` event.
            log4(
                0, // Start of data (0, since no data).
                0, // End of data (0, since no data).
                _TRANSFER_EVENT_SIGNATURE, // Signature.
                from, // `from`.
                toMasked, // `to`.
                tokenId // `tokenId`.
            )
        }
        if (toMasked == 0) _revert(TransferToZeroAddress.selector);

        _afterTokenTransfers(from, to, tokenId, 1);
    }
```

What should I do? I can add approve to a previous transaction, but that is inefficient. I removed this part:

```
if (!_isSenderApprovedOrOwner(approvedAddress, from, _msgSenderERC721A()))
            if (!isApprovedForAll(from, _msgSenderERC721A())) _revert(TransferCallerNotOwnerNorApproved.selector);
```

and it works then, but I am unsure if the function is safe.